# vueJS - Using 'this' in a callback function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

EDIT --- SOLVED

It turns out that isn't really a problem, Vue will auto-bind for you so there's no need to bind manually.

END EDIT ---

I'm trying to pass a method to a callback(or event) to a child component.
Everything works great, except that the `function` executes in the wrong context.

In react, I would bind the `functions` in the `constructor`, I'm not sure what's the solution is in `Vue`.

Example

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header/>
    <Tasks 
    :todos="todos"
    @onMarkAsDone="markAsDone"
    >
    </Tasks>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import Tasks from './components/Tasks.vue';

export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Tasks',
      todos: [{
        id:0,
        text:'Complete this by lunch',
        isDone: false
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    markAsDone(id) {
      console.log(this); // refers to the child component
      // can't access this.todos
    }
  },
  components: {
    Tasks,
    Header
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Normally you could try the arrow function syntax to keep the lexical context of `this`. But as I know there's some hacky `proxy` for this in Vue. Can you reproduce a runnable code of problem?

Comment: 1. I don't understand what you want to achieve. 2. If there is child-parent relation show also child component code.

Comment: Child component is unfortunately irrelevant, as it doesn't matter "why" this callback is triggered, it still can't the right 'this' -- in any case I'll answer my own question as I figured out it can be done in a 'created' method of the life cycle

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution to it, turns out you can use the 'created' life cycle hook, this is similar to react when binding in a constructor

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Header/>
    <Tasks 
    :todos="todos"
    @onMarkAsDone="markAsDone"
    >
    </Tasks>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './components/Header.vue';
import Tasks from './components/Tasks.vue';

export default {
  name: 'my-component',
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Tasks',
      todos: [{
        id:0,
        text:'Complete this by lunch',
        isDone: false
      }]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    markAsDone(id) {
      console.log(this.todos); // can now access the correct 'this'
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.markAsDone = this.markAsDone.bind(this);
  },
  components: {
    Tasks,
    Header
  }
}
</script>
```

Sub component code

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li 
      :class="{isDone:todo.isDone}"
      :key="todo.id" 
      v-for="todo in todos">
      <input type='checkbox' @change="markAsDone(todo.id)"/>
       {{todo.text}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Tasks',
  props: ['todos'],
  methods: {
    markAsDone(id) {
      this.$emit('onMarkAsDone', id);
    } 
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you can, please give the code in the `Task` component. I think the `this` will be auto-correct in Vue due to a magical thing called `proxy`. I'm curious how it could be wrong here. If you can do `bind(this)` in `created` like the code above, you can also do arrow function syntax `markAsDone = (id) => {}` instead to achieve `this`-fixing, it would be cleaner, no need to bind. I do the same hack in React - arrow function instead of bind.

Comment: I'll add the component code, however it's not relevant. in any case using markAsDone = (id) => {} will create a different problem, as now 'this' will be undefined (feel free to try it). - this occures because the 'this' is set on code execution, which is the module itself

Comment: Vue automatically binds all the functions in `methods` to the current instance. It shouldn't be necessary to call `bind` yourself. There must be something else going on here.

Comment: @skirtle - Yea you're right, I just removed my bind and it still works, I must've tried to access the wrong attribute and assumed it was a bind issue

Answer (score 0):

You can return function in a `markAsDone` method, like this:

```
markAsDone() {
  return id => {
    console.log(this.todos);
  }
},
```

and then when passing method as a prop call it:

```
:onMarkAsDone="markAsDone()"
```

Then you can call the prop method inside your Child-Component.

That should give you requested functionality without using `bind` in `created()` hook.

Comment: Good call, but you must admit it looks a bit iffy :)

Comment: Nothing will invoke that inner arrow function. It'll just call `markAsDone` when the event occurs and that will return a function that will be ignored.

Comment: @skirtle I assumed he calls the function in a child component. I updated my asnwer. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: But it isn't a prop, it's an event listener. The child won't have access to it.